# using a variable in a mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return a value from my database based on a user input on my form. 
When I run the code using a value it works but when I put in the variable it doesn't. I am sure it is something simple, but I just don't get it?

Here is the code that works:

```
$sql_beam = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cost_ft FROM Beams WHERE number = '201'");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_beam))
{
  echo "<p>" . $row['cost_ft'] . "</p>";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

When I change it to this it doesn't:

```
$beam_num = $_POST['Beam Number'];

$sql_beam = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cost_ft FROM Beams WHERE number = '$beam_num'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_beam))
{
  echo "<p>" . $row['cost_ft'] . "</p>";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: try printing the value of `$_POST['Beam Number']` before the query and check if its empty or not.

Comment: You're using MySQLi, so you should be using prepared statements!  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never put any variable directly into a query. Google sql injection and how to prevent it.

Here is a simple example:

```
$sql = "SELECT cost_ft FROM Beams WHERE number = ?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $beam_num);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<p>" . $row['cost_ft'] . "</p>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: going to show my ignorance, how do I debug $_POST['Beam Number']?

Comment: I included that in my edit using `error_log()`. To debug a variable just means to examine that value of it at a particular point in your code. If you don't know where your error log is, then just echo the value to your browser if you are developing lcoalyl then search for how to find it.

Comment: got it, it was a problem with the form like you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Variables in a query work best when enclosed in curly brackets like this:

```
$beam_num = $_POST['Beam Number'];

$sql_beam = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cost_ft FROM Beams WHERE number = '{$beam_num}'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_beam))
{
  echo "<p>" . $row['cost_ft'] . "</p>";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

That should solve the problem, if it doesnt then try this:

```
$sql_beam = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cost_ft FROM Beams WHERE number = $beam_num");
```

I had that in one of my codes and it worked.

Comment: Backticks are for table and columns; single quotes are for non-integer variables you're passing in. In this case, the quotes were correct originally.

Comment: Thanks for the help andrewsi and pattyd, It turned out to be a problem with the form, not the php.

Comment: WARNING! A very bad answer introducing SQL injection!

Answer (score -2):

Change your second line to this:

```
$sql_beam = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT cost_ft FROM Beams WHERE number = '". $beam_num ."'");
```

Comment: That will result in the exact same string wouldn't it. His syntax is fine as far as I can tell. A variable in a double quoted string should be evaluated.